# Oracle java connection

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I have written a connection code with oracle. But still I am getting errors.  I'll type the code of mine here.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SimpleOraJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        String serverName="10.20.228.67";
        String user="root";
        String password="root";
        String SID="abc";
        String URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+serverName+":"+1520+":"+SID;
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
        String SQL="Select employeename from employee";
        Statement stat=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(SQL);
        while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

    }
stat.close();
conn.close();
}
}
```

It shows error in this line:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

The error is on the word Oracle. It is asking me to create class in package `oracle.jdbc.driver`

Please somebody help!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, assuming that class-paths are set up, and the appropriate .jar files are in the correct directories, the first thing that jumps out is I believe you need to import the package into your class.  There should be a `import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;` line under the `import java.sql.*;` line also the DriverManager call should be 
`DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());`
with the lowercase o, it's capitalized in your code.
Another thing might be, the version of the Oracle JDBC, and Oracle client you're using.  According to this [OTN Discussion post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=201) Oracle JDBC 10.2 is the last release to support the package oracle.jdbc.driver.

So basically according to the metalink page if you're using a JDBC 10.2 or older client, something like this will work:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class myjdbcapp
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
  {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:orcl";
    String userName = "scott";
    String password = "tiger";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
    OracleCallableStatement myprocst  = (OracleCallableStatement)
    conn.prepareCall ("begin myproc(?); end;");
  // ...
  }

}
```

Clients newer than JDBC 10.2 will need to change import oracle.jdbc.driver.*; to import oracle.jdbc.*;

Answer (score 3):

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

The package is `oracle.jdbc.driver` with a lowercase `o`.